# Does Magento 1 store customer's credit card information in our database

Tags: magento-1.9, credit-card

I have enabled Paypal and Credit Card/ Debit Card payment method option.
I want to know whether customer's credit card information are stored in magento 1 database when they pay using these 2 payment method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these two tables "`sales_flat_quote_payment`"
"`sales_flat_order_payment`" ?

Two table "`sales_flat_quote_payment`" and "`sales_flat_order_payment`" store credit card number based on payment method config. If your payment method hold this following config then credit card information not save into database, so you can control credit card information save from code.

```
protected $_canSaveCc   = false;
```

Comment: where can i find this code protected $_canSaveCc = false;?

Comment: Should be in Model/Payment.php or in your payment model class                                                             $_canSaveCc = false; .//app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Direct.php:96: protected $_canSaveCc = false; .//app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Hostedpro.php:64: protected $_canSaveCc = false; .//app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php:203: protected $_canSaveCc = false;

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you, so it will help to others in Magento community.

Comment: I did not get your first point Should be in Model/Payment.php or in your payment model class